# Marrying Rails to an HTML form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am very new to Rails, and been asking lots of questions recently, I'm getting increasingly frustrated with figuring out how to work things in rails (i.e logging to console, routes, etc..), now I'm trying to figure out how to communicate between an HTML form (and please raw HTML, not form helpers or any of that voodoo magic, I really am trying very hard to like rails, so one thing at a time), if you want to add helpers, please explain what they are doing, where they go, how to use, etc...

I've tried all the examples on the first/second google page (gruesome I know! second google page?!)
What I am looking for is an example, and an explanation.

Also, how does it fit in with routes? (i.e what would be the proper way of setting up a controller/view, and routing them without the controller in the URL)

Please keep in mind, I am not using any models, just controllers, and views.

Your thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried doing a Rails tutorial? The [Rails Tutorial Book](http://www.railstutorial.org/book) is, probably, the most widely used and updated one. It has a ton of useful information. It takes you through making a whole application, explaining carefully the routes, forms, helpers, models, controllers, views, etc. It only assumes you kind of sort of understanding programming and are comfortable with websites in general. It's a great resource. I'd suggest doing the tutorial, and I think along the way you'd answer these questions and learn a lot.

Comment: Yeah, I've been meaning to read that book, but I'm reading 4 books ATM, so I thought maybe I could jump head in and start trying to figure stuff out.
Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: voodoo magic? then why use Rails at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh no! Sorry that Rails is giving you grief, especially about form helpers! It's a shame because Rails' form helpers are pretty great, and IMHO are a super useful part of Rails in reducing code duplication, and allowing you to not worry about the specific field names that you are submitting to a server. (They're hard to get accustomed to, but worth it.)

Let me give you a summary of Rails form helpers. For starters, let's take this a simple example

```
<form action='/users' method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='username' />
    <input type='password' name='password' />
    <input type='submit' name='Create user' />
</form>
```

Ah, the most basic user signup form imaginable. This will POST to /users, which is REST-convention for "create a user".

The [Rails Routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) tells you that if you have a controller `UsersController` (in app/controllers/users_controller.rb -- the filename must be exactly this) and a route `resources :users`, then this will call the code in the `create` method of UsersController, and you will have access to the form POST data via the `params` hash, i.e. `params[:username]`, `params[:password]`, etc.

It is in that controller action where you would create an instance of your `User` model and save it to the database. (If you aren't using models, you're missing out on most of the magic of Rails's forms.)

Okay. So far so good, right?

Let's spice things up a bit by using Rails's form helpers.

A quick rewrite of the form using basic Rails form helpers would look something like this.

```
<%= form_tag '/users', method: 'POST' do %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'username' %>
    <%= password_tag 'password' %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Create User' %>
<% end %>
```

So far, no Rails magic - it's a straight translation into HTML.

Let's add some Rails *marrying*.

Again, assuming you have a `User` model with a `username` column and a `password` attribute (`attr_accessor :password`), and your `UsersController`'s `#new` method looks like this:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end
```

Then, in this form (which lives in `app/views/users/new.html.erb`), you can use that unpersisted `User` object to make the form more intelligent:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>
  <%= f.password :password %>
  <%= f.submit 'Create User' %>
<% end %>
```

Note the `do |f|` part of the `form_for` line. The `f` is a form object, which remembers the object it describes. So, you can call `f.text_field :username`, and the field will magically have the existing value of `@user.username` populated as the `value` of the `<input>`.

Then, if you have a `UsersController#create` method that looks something like this:

```
def create
  # Instantiate a new user with the inputted parameters from the form
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  if @user.save
    # user is saved successfully! redirect somewhere....
  else
    # user couldn't be saved successfully, because of some rule that you
    # define on the User model - like making sure that usernames are
    # unique, or something like that.
    #
    # so, we can use the attributes on @user to prepopulate the new user form
    render :new
  end
end
```

Anyway, I hope that gives you a good overview of why Rails form helpers can be useful, and how to use them with your models. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Yes! very much, that was an absolutely brilliant answer, It's so hard to piece things together, at the beginning, my apologies for the frustration.
I do however have a question, assume I want to have my own function (i.e createUser), how can I call that from form_tag? that's the part thats giving me trouble)
For example, I managed to put together a form that that does post to a method, but I get this:
'No route matches {:action=>"search", :controller=>"index", :method=>"get"}' any advice on configuring the routes?

Comment: to call a function in your viewer, you would use instance variable. example: in the controller, when you create a new user, you'd save the user in an instance variable @user = User.create(user_attribute1, user_attribute2).

Comment: The best way to learn configuring routs is to follow Rails Restful convention. Let's say in your routes.rb file, you have  `Get 'post/index' => 'posts#index'`, your controller's file name would be posts_controllers.rb. inside there you would have an action named 'index' as in this: `def index end`.  in your views: you will have this file structure: `views/posts/index.html`. So the naming conventions matter.

Comment: If you through this [tutorial](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), you will easily pickup how routes, controller, views are interconnected. It is basic but great tutorial for beginners. It helped me when I was starting.

Comment: `'No route matches {:action=>"search", :controller=>"index", :method=>"get"}'` means you have a controller name `IndexControllers` (`index_controllers.rb`) but you don't have an action called `search` as in `def search end`. just add the action in the controller and it'll go away

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I added the route you mentioned, and it stopped coming up, but now I'm getting this: 'No route matches [POST] "/index/search"'

Comment: @MrHaze, if you run `bundle exec rake routes`, you will see all the routes that are configured, along with what controller + action they map to. It's in the same general style as [the Rails Routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), so hopefully that will give you a point of reference.

Comment: Thanks guys, you have been very helpful :)